# Possible to supply wildcard to aws S3 batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to run an S3 batch job.
To do that S3 requires a manifest (*.csv) telling it what objects to iterate over.
Well my bucket has 1.2 billion objects in it.
But, I **don't** want to make a CSV file with 1.2 billions lines of text.

Can I simply have a wildcard in my manifest file (*.csv file) telling it to iterate over all the objects in the bucket?

i.e.

```
mybucket,*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't specify "all objects", to the best of my knowledge. You can, however, supply an Amazon S3 inventory report.

I suspect that the reason that you cannot specify "all objects" is precisely because there are buckets with billions of objects and the time for S3 Batch to enumerate them would be significant. Also, what should the behavior be if objects are added to the bucket after the batch starts, and how would they be detected? How would the customer know which objects had been processed, and which had not?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm aware of the inventory report.

Comment: I figured you would be, but just checking. Unfortunately, I don't think the answer you want is out there.